# Xlsxwriter conditional formatting in loop problem

Tags: pandas, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I Have Pandas pivot dataframe with multiheader and to which i am applying condition formatting on few columns only in loop(e.g, 6,7,9,10,12,13...) I ahve used for Loop as below:

```py
    for i in range(6,len(df1.columns),3):
            print(i)
            worksheet.conditional_format(4,int(i),len(df1)+3,int(i+1), {'type':     'cell', \
                                            'criteria': '>=', \
                                            'value':'45',\
                                            'format':   format1
                                        })
```

This makes my excel output corrupted & also if I repair Excel, I can see my header shifted by 1 cell. Also, there is no conditional formatting done in that excel. Can anyone please help to resolve the issue?
Also If I remove this line from code output is fine but without conditional format.

Here is sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
th='30000'
cars = {'day':['aug','aug','sep','sep','aug'],
        'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4','Hyundai Elite i20'],
        'Type':['sedan,','sedan','hatchback','hatchback','hatchback'],
        'Down Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000,10000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['day','Brand', 'Type','Down Price'])
dfpivot=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['day'],columns=['Brand','Type'],values=['Down Price'],aggfunc=np.max)
with pd.ExcelWriter(OUTPATH+'Report.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:

    dfpivot.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'data')
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['data']
    format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})
    for i in range(1,len(dfpivot.columns),1):
            print(i)
            worksheet.conditional_format(4,int(i),len(df1)+3,int(i+1), {'type':     'cell', \
                                            'criteria': '>=', \
                                            'value':th,\
                                            'format':   format1
                                    })
writer.save()
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It means we must be able to copy your code , run it on our machines and get the same problem you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reformatted your code and fixed a few minor issues:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

threshold = '30000'
cars = {'day': ['aug', 'aug', 'sep', 'sep', 'aug'],
        'Brand': ['Honda Civic', 'Toyota Corolla', 'Ford Focus',
                  'Audi A4', 'Hyundai Elite i20'],
        'Type': ['sedan,', 'sedan', 'hatchback', 'hatchback', 'hatchback'],
        'Down Price': [22000, 25000, 27000, 35000, 10000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns=['day', 'Brand', 'Type', 'Down Price'])
dfpivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['day'],
                         columns=['Brand', 'Type'],
                         values=['Down Price'], aggfunc=np.max)

with pd.ExcelWriter('Report.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:

    dfpivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='data')
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['data']
    format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                                   'font_color': '#9C0006'})
    max_column = len(cars['Brand'])
    worksheet.set_column(1, max_column, 15)

    for i in range(1, len(dfpivot.columns), 1):
            print(i)
            worksheet.conditional_format(4, i, len(df) + 3, i + 1,
                                         {'type': 'cell',
                                          'criteria': '>=',
                                          'value': threshold,
                                          'format': format1})
```

It runs and the output file has conditional formatting:

[image]

So, the XlsxWriter code works. However, the ranges don't look right (they are overlapping) so you should check that you are using the correct row and column numbers.

Also, it probably isn't necessary to have separate conditional formats since the criteria is the same in all cases. It would probably be enough to create one conditional format outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, it helps. I have corrected ranges and it worked